# setup kubernetes worker node behind NAT

Tags: kubernetes

I have setup a kubernetes cluster using kubeadm.

**Environment**

1. Master node installed in a PC with public IP.
2. Worker node behind NAT address (the interface has local internal IP, but needs to be accessed using the public IP)

**Status**

The worker node is able to join the cluster and running

```
kubectl get nodes
```

the status of the node is ready.

Kubernetes can deploy and run pods on that node.

**Problem**

The problem that I have is that I'm not able to access the pods deployed on that node. For example, if I run

```
kubectl logs <pod-name>
```

where pod-name is the name of a pod deployed on the worker node, I have this error:

```
Error from server: Get https://192.168.0.17:10250/containerLogs/default/stage-bbcf4f47f-gtvrd/stage: dial tcp 192.168.0.17:10250: i/o timeout
```

because it is trying to use the local IP 192.168.0.17, which is not accessable externally.

I have seen that the node had this annotation:

```
flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: 192.168.0.17
```

So, I have tried to modify the annotation, setting the external IP, in this way:

```
flannel.alpha.coreos.com/public-ip: <my_externeal_ip>
```

and I see that the node is correctly annotated, but it is still using 192.168.0.17.

Is there something else that I have to setup in the worker node or in the cluster configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*there were a metric boatload of Related questions in the sidebar, and I'm about 90% certain this is a FAQ, but can't be bothered to triage the Duplicate*

> Is there something else that I have to setup in the worker node or in the cluster configuration?

No, that situation is not a misconfiguration of your worker Node, nor your cluster configuration. It is just a side-effect of the way kubernetes handles Pod-centric traffic. It does mean that if you choose to go forward with that setup, you will not be able to use `kubectl exec` nor `kubectl logs` (and I think `port-forward`, too) since those commands do not send traffic through the API server, rather it directly contacts the `kubelet` port on the Node which hosts the Pod you are interacting with. That's primarily to offload the traffic from traveling through the API server, but can also be a scaling issue if you have a sufficiently large number of exec/log/port-foward/etc commands happening simultaneously, since TCP ports are not infinite.

I think it is *theoretically* possible to have your workstation join the overlay network, since by definition it's not related to the outer network, but I don't have a ton of experience with trying to get an overlay to play nice-nice with NAT, so that's the "theoretically" part.

I have personally gotten Wireguard to work across NAT, meaning you could VPN into your Node's network, but it was some gear turning, and is likely more trouble than it's worth.